# use escape character for a sqlsave command on a data frame column with a single quote in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R with multiple columns. I want to write this dataframe to a SQL Server database tables. I use RODBC package with sqlsave command. The command runs fine until you hit one of the column that has a name with a single quote in it (Kevin O'Donnell). I wanted to write an escape character before the ' to insert this row in a data frame.

Here is what I tried:

```
sqlSave(dbhandle,df,tablename = "DBTable",append = TRUE,
        rownames = TRUE, colnames = FALSE, verbose = TRUE, safer = TRUE, 
        addPK = TRUE, typeInfo, 
        varTypes, fast = FALSE, test = FALSE, nastring = NULL)
#Error here is
sqlwrite returned 
42000 102 [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'Donnell'.
42000 105 [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ' )'

df$MerchantName = gsub("'","\'",df$MerchantName)
```

It didnt replace the ' with ' to help with escape characters

Answer (score 0):

Keep the rest of the code, but try changing the gsub line to this:

```
df$MerchantName = gsub("'","\\'",df$MerchantName, fixed=TRUE)
```

Notice how you need to escape the escape, to make sure it gets passed as part of the string to the external service that your sql server is.

Also note `fixed=TRUE` to make sure it actually does what it looks like it should.

**EDIT:**

added fixed=TRUE to skip the regex evaluation that would have otherwise done away with the double backslash.

**EDIT 2:**

Try this escape instead:

```
df$MerchantName = gsub("'","''",df$MerchantName, fixed=TRUE)
```

Sometimes a double single quote is used to escape a single quote.

Comment: It did create the escape character as you would expect using the code but the sqlSave command still did not accept a Kevin O\'Donnell string into the database table

Comment: I updated the code with another possbile escape. Perhaps you could say which sql server this is?

Comment: Hi ! Yes, the error is the same. I will try your new code and let you know what happens